# Docker SSL-Handshake not working. How to debug?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose

I use docker for my Django powered projects and can not access https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com over the request library in our production environment. The request library "hangs" on the SSL-Handshake for ever.

So I decided to try it with curl. Same problem:
Calling

```
curl https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com
```

just hangs for ever.

If I run this container on my local machine, and run curl => everything works fine.
IF I run the curl command on the host machine directly, it also works fine.

Any idea what could be wrong or what I could to debug this problem?

I also tried for example

```
curl https://www.google.com
curl https://www.bing.com
```

And that works. It is just the microsofttranslator.com page which is not working magically.

**EDIT**: Running this command in the container leads to this output:

```
    curl --verbose https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com
*   Trying 20.50.1.17:443...
* Connected to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com (20.50.1.17) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: If the CA certificates in your container are outdated, it's possible your app is blocking when trying to verify the certificate of the service. Are you able to shell into the container and try `curl --verbose https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com`, the output should (!) include `SSL certificate verify ok`

Comment: I don't see "SSL certificate verify ok" in this container. I use this official container: 3.11.8-slim-bookworm. I do not understand why it works on my local machine and not on the productive machine.

Comment: It's possible that your local machine and the container image have different sets of intermediate and root CAs. It's important to keep these current. Unless you're periodically refreshing container images, the trust stores won't be updated. I just ran `curl` inside the latest (index digest [`sha256:a2eb07f336e4f194358382611b4fea136c632b40baa6314cb27a366deeaf0144`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3.11.8-slim-bookworm/images/sha256-4bcdb5d5bc81caf410bc880ca7d47d6ce3f05dc50f81166eb42827fcdc98cfca?context=explore) and it verifies. Suggest you pull this and try again

Comment: You can confirm the current index|repo digest (before you `pull` the latest) with `docker inspect --format='{{.RepoDigests}}' python:3.11.8-slim-bookworm`. I suspect (!?) your current image is not the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The host system is using an MTU=1450.
My docker compose did not apply automatically this value. So it was set to MTU=1500

I had to set the network manually to a MTU=1450 value with:

```
networks:
  internal_network:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450
```